# Postgres Multiple Rows as Single Row

Tags: postgresql, birt

I know I need to use sub-queries for this, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I have multiple entries per column ID, but I want to display them as a single row. Here's the table design:

```
UUID | position_id | spot
-----+-------------+-----
111  |    1        | left
112  |    1        | right
113  |    3        | center
114  |    4        | right
```

The way I want to output this data is such:

```
postion_1_left | position_1_right | postion_3_center | position_4_right
---------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------
     true      |      true        |      true        |      true
```

The reason for this is that I want to put this data into a BIRT report, and having absolute values for each position_id and spot as true or false would make the report much nicer. The report would look as such:

```
             left  | center | right
-----------+-------+--------+-----------
position 1 | yes   |  no    |  yes
position 2 | no    |  no    |  no
position 3 | no    |  yes   |  no
position 4 | no    |  no    |  yes
```

I cannot think of a better way of doing this, so if anyone has a suggestion I'm open to it. Otherwise I'll proceed with this layout but I'm having a hard time coming up with the query. I tried starting with a query like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT spot FROM positions_table WHERE position_id = 3 AND spot = 'left')
from positions_table
WHERE uuid = 'afb36733'
```

But obviously that wouldn't work.

Comment: Try to start from `select pos.id, bool_or(spot = 'left') as left from generate_series(1,4) as pos(id) left join your_table on (pos.id = position_id) group by pos.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you simple want to check if you have a given `spot` out of a finite list - `('left', 'center', 'right')` - for each `position_id`, I see a very simple solution for your case using [`bool_or` aggregation function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) (see [also on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a621/2)):

```
SELECT
    pt.position_id,
    bool_or(pt.spot = 'left') AS left,
    bool_or(pt.spot = 'right') AS right,
    bool_or(pt.spot = 'center') AS center
FROM
    positions_table pt
GROUP BY
    pt.position_id
ORDER BY
    pt.position_id;
```

Result:

```
 position_id | left | right | center 
-------------+------+-------+--------
           1 | t    | t     | f
           3 | f    | f     | t
           4 | f    | t     | f
(3 rows)
```

You can then expand it with `CASE` to format better (or do that in your presentation layer):

```
SELECT
    pt.position_id,
    CASE WHEN bool_or(pt.spot = 'left') THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS left,
    CASE WHEN bool_or(pt.spot = 'right') THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS right,
    CASE WHEN bool_or(pt.spot = 'center') THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS center
FROM
    positions_table pt
GROUP BY
    pt.position_id
ORDER BY
    pt.position_id;
```

Result:

```
 position_id | left | right | center 
-------------+------+-------+--------
           1 | yes  | yes   | no
           3 | no   | no    | yes
           4 | no   | yes   | no
(3 rows)
```

Another common options of pivoting would be:

- [using `crosstab` function from `tablefunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html)
- [using `FILTER` clause or `CASE` inside aggregation function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html)

But as it is only true/false, `bool_or` seems more than enough here.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `generate_series()` to fill gaps in `position_ids` and aggregate `spots` to array for `id`:

```
select 
    id, 
    coalesce('left' = any(arr), false) as left,
    coalesce('center' = any(arr), false) as center,
    coalesce('right' = any(arr), false) as right
from (
    select id, array_agg(spot) arr
    from generate_series(1, 4) id
    left join positions_table on id = position_id
    group by 1
    ) s
order by 1;

 id | left | center | right 
----+------+--------+-------
  1 | t    | f      | t
  2 | f    | f      | f
  3 | f    | t      | f
  4 | f    | f      | t
(4 rows)
```

Comment: This is a great solution. But I went with the other response with the CASE statements. Thanks for replying.